# Python pandas. Замена значения столбца на среднее значение по двум столбцам

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня есть таблица:

```
|    | Id | Name | City | Address | Numb |
|----|----|------|------|---------|------|
| 0  | 0  | Аб   | Пит  | Ацыа    | 1.0  |
| 1  | 1  | Ва   | Моск | ываыв   | 2.0  |
| 2  | 2  | Аб   | Пит  | ыаыв    | NaN  |
| 3  | 3  | Ге   | Дне  | цуцк    | 3.0  |
| 4  | 4  | Се   | Уф   | йыв     | 2.0  |
| 5  | 5  | Аб   | Моск | ЫВАыва  | 2.0  |
| 6  | 6  | Ва   | Уф   | ЫВАыв   | 2.0  |
| 7  | 7  | Аб   | Пит  | Ыа 123  | 1.0  |
| 8  | 8  | Де   | Кип  | ыфа 2ц3 | 5.0  |
| 9  | 9  | Аб   | Пит  | Ука 2   | -1.0 |
| 10 | 10 | МРЕ  | Кип  | ыва 2   | 3.0  |
```

Мне нужно заменить все значения в колонке Numb, которые не удовлетворяют условию Numb = (1,2,3). Заменить нужно на наиболее часто встречающимся значением по колонке Numb и City.
Т.е для Id = 2, Numb = 1, т.к. для City Пит значения Num = 1, 1, -1 (наиболее часто встречающиеся 1).
Были попытки что-то типа такого:

```
for idx, row in S1[-S1['Numb'].isin([1, 2, 3])].iterrows():
    S1.at[idx, 'Numb'] = S1[S1['City'] == S1.at[idx, 'City']] == S1.at[idx]['Numb'].mode()[0]
```

Вылетает с ошибкой:
TypeError: _get_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: А присвоение  S1.at[idx, 'Numb'] значения типа bool -  это так задумано?

Comment: @passant, Нет, так не было задумано

Comment: Ну так исправьте и расскажите, что получилось.

Comment: @passant, путаница в скобках и лишнее сравнение :(

Comment: То-есть проблема решена? Ну и чудненько.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы советовал избегать iterrows вообще, так как это один из самых неэффективных методов pandas. Кроме того, вашу задачу можно решить векторизированными способами pandas, не прибегая к циклу:

Исходный df:

```
    Id Name  City  Address  Numb
0    0   Аб   Пит     Ацыа   1.0
1    1   Ва  Моск    ываыв   2.0
2    2   Аб   Пит     ыаыв   NaN
3    3   Ге   Дне     цуцк   3.0
4    4   Се    Уф      йыв   2.0
5    5   Аб  Моск   ЫВАыва   2.0
6    6   Ва    Уф    ЫВАыв   2.0
7    7   Аб   Пит   Ыа_123   1.0
8    8   Де   Кип  ыфа_2ц3   5.0
9    9   Аб   Пит    Ука_2  -1.0
10  10  МРЕ   Кип    ыва_2   3.0
```

Преобразуем, принимая во внимание, что моду нужно считать без учета выпадающих из промежутка (1, 2, 3) чисел, если я вас правильно понял, а не так, как это делаете вы:

```
df.loc[~df['Numb'].isin((1,2,3)), 'Numb']=np.nan
df['mode'] = df.groupby('City')['Numb'].transform(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
df['Numb'].fillna(df['mode'], inplace=True)
```

Получаем результат. колонку с модой можно удалить по желанию:

```
   Id Name  City  Address  Numb  mode
0    0   Аб   Пит     Ацыа   1.0   1.0
1    1   Ва  Моск    ываыв   2.0   2.0
2    2   Аб   Пит     ыаыв   1.0   1.0
3    3   Ге   Дне     цуцк   3.0   3.0
4    4   Се    Уф      йыв   2.0   2.0
5    5   Аб  Моск   ЫВАыва   2.0   2.0
6    6   Ва    Уф    ЫВАыв   2.0   2.0
7    7   Аб   Пит   Ыа_123   1.0   1.0
8    8   Де   Кип  ыфа_2ц3   3.0   3.0
9    9   Аб   Пит    Ука_2   1.0   1.0
10  10  МРЕ   Кип    ыва_2   3.0   3.0
```